# Что-то вроде комбинаторики

Tags: комбинаторика

Есть такая задача: имеются 2 последовательности (возможно разной длины, не меньше 1). Во вторую закинули элементы первой (возможно не все), перемешав их. Нужно определить, можно ли заново из второй последовательности собрать первую. Допускается, что во вторую могли подкинуть лишние элементы.

Примеры:

1 2 3 4 и 3 2 1

Можно пересобрать, только одним способом.

1 2 1 и 2 1 1

Можно, но разными способами, так как неизвестно, на каком месте стояла каждая единица.

1 2 1 и 1 2 3

Нельзя, так как тройки не было в первой.

1 2 3 и 1 2 2

Нельзя, так как в первой была одна двойка, а во второй их две.
Может есть математические формулы для такого?

Comment: Трижды прочитал, но ничего не понял. Наверное, стоит объяснить получше

Comment: Вопрос читается легче если учесть что в парах последовательностей автор первую последовательность пишет второй а вторую первой. :)

Comment: Перебирайте элементы первой последовательности и вычёркивайте их из второй. Если это удалось сделать для всей первой последовательности, то ответ - да. Иначе - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте уберем первую часть — о перемешивании, и задача сразу станет простой: можно ли из элементов первого мультимножества А собрать второе мультимножество В. Т.е. математическая — является ли второе мультимножество подмножеством первого.

Формула, собственно — верно ли соотношение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реализация на С++ — с использованием стандартной библиотечной функции [`includes`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes).

Комбинаторика тут в полной мере ни при чем...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy OK, заменим на "мультимножество". Хотя в данном случае `set` и `multiset` в принципе не используются.